# Create a list with a costum background for every list item

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview

I just started with Android and I searching online I can't find a solution to my problem:

I have a hashmap, where the key is the name of a course and the value is the number of days I have before the deadline. I want to make  a list out of this hashmap where the item has a red background color if I have less than 1/2 days, otherwise it has a green color.

I started using Array Adapters, but I can't find a solution to it:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    R.layout.list_costum_text, R.id.list_content, values);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

At the moment "values" is just an array with the name of the courses.
I am looking now at Costum adapters, but I still have some problems with them

Edit:

If I follow the tutorial on vogella I can make this work (I am modifying the main activity):

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
  super.onCreate(icicle);

   String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
    "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
    "Linux", "OS/2" };

   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    R.layout.list_costum_text, R.id.red_list, values);

setListAdapter(adapter);




setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }
 }
```

where activity_main.xml is a ListView layout, list_costum_text contains two edit text (one is red_list).

I can't understand how a custom adapter works, also because I am not able to test it in the main activity!

Comment: I have added some code to my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should create your custom adapter by extending ArrayAdapter and then write your own getView() method.

ADDITIONAL INFO AFTER REQUEST IN THE COMMENTS

What any adapter roughly does is: it takes your xml layout for each item, inflates and then populates UI elements with values.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    textView.setText(values[position]);
    // Change the icon for Windows and iPhone
    String s = values[position];
    if (s.startsWith("iPhone")) {
      imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no);
    } else {
      imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
    }
return rowView;
```

}

This is just an example taken from http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html but you will get the idea. It is not hard.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am looking into getView(), but I don't really understand how I should override that method. It seems confusing, and the examples online don't clarify

Comment: @android_help Pleas take a look at the example. which I added.